# Trigonometric series which is dominated pointwise convergent to Lebesgue integrable but not improperly Riemann integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

I'm looking for an example of a trigonometric series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n \sin(nx) + b_n \cos(nx))
$$
such that:

1. The series converges pointwise on $[0,2\pi]$
2. The sum of the series is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,2\pi]$.
3. The sum of the series is **not** improperly Riemann integrable on $[0,2\pi]$.
4. The partial sums satisfy $|s_N| \leq g$ for some $g \in L^1([0,2\pi])$

Motivation: I'd like an example of a trigonometric series that cannot be integrated as either a Riemann or improper Riemann integral, but can be integrated term-by-term as a Lebesgue integral. This would illustrate the power of the Lebesgue integral with a (hopefully) natural example. (I know a standard example is a sequence converging pointwise to the indicator function of the rationals, but I don't consider this very natural.)

<strike>Even better if the partial sums satisfy
$$
\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\sum_{n=0}^{N} |a_n \sin(nx) + b_n \cos(nx)| \leq g(x),} 
$$
so that the dominated convergence theorem lets us use term-by-term integration to show that $a_n,b_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of the sum.</strike>

Edit: Conditions 1 and 4 already allow us to use the dominated convergence theorem to compute the coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ by term-by-term integration of $\sin(kx)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)$ and $\cos(kx)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)$.

Comment: This seems like a tough problem. What is the motivation for such an example? I'm curious about the non-Riemann integrability condition paired with the pointwise convergence one.

Comment: @Jose27 I'd like an example of a trigonometric series that cannot be integrated as either a Riemann or improper Riemann integral, but can be integrated term-by-term as a Lebesgue integral. This would illustrate the power of the Lebesgue integral with a (hopefully) natural example.

Comment: Is it clear that condition 4. guarantees you can Lebesgue integrate term by term? Or otherwise, how do your conditions guarantee that you can Lebesgue integrate term by term?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Let $A_n$ be the $n$-th term of the series. So the $N$-th partial sum is $s_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n$. Conditions 1. and 4. let us apply the domianted convergence theorem to the sequence of partial sums. Here's the calculation:   $\int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \int \lim_N \sum_{n=1}^N A_n = \lim_N \int \sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n =  \lim_N \sum_{n=1}^{N} \int A_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int A_n$. The second equality is by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Right, of course. I don't think the example you are looking for can also satisfy the last condition you mention, that $\sum_{n=0}^N |a_n\sin(nx)+b_n\cos(nx)|\le g(x)$, since then the series will be absolutely (and hence, uniformly) convergent. So I think that $|s_N|\le g(x)$ may be the best we can hope for. Although, if the bound only holds almost everywhere instead of literally pointwise, then maybe this is also still possible, but it does seem more technical.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Does pointwise absolute convergence imply uniform convergence here?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Also, does the last condition even guarantee pointwise absolute convergence?

Comment: Hm, I was actually thinking of $\sum(|a_n|+|b_n|)<\infty$, which would imply uniform convergence. It's not clear to me if pointwise absolute convergence would imply uniform convergence too. The last condition says the partial sums are bounded at each point $x$ where $g(x)<\infty$. By monotone convergence, the series is finite.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz And, finally, it has just occurred to me that condition 4 already allows use to compute $a_k$ and $b_k$ by term-by-term integration of $\sin(kx)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and $\cos(kx)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz You're quite right that the last condition does impliy pointwise absolute convergence when $g(x)<\infty$. Thanks. I'm also glad we sorted out that uniform convergence does not seem to be implied.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz I crossed out the last condition because it is not needed. Thanks for your comments about it though.